# Whats the difference between a normal instruction and a fast instruction in java (e.g. aload and fast_aload)

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-11, instructions

I printed out the executed bytecodes of a simple java program and noticed that some java instructions are fast_xxxx instead of the normal instruction.

I could not find anything about that in the JVM Specification.
So what exactly is the difference between these instructions and when/why does the interpreter choose to use these?

*Edit*: The bytecodes were printed with the `-XX:TraceBytecodes` option.

Comment: What was the simple program, and how did you print out its bytecode?

Comment: I printed the executed bytecodes with the -XX:TraceBytecodes option. The program just has two prints

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496211/2711488), especially the second part.

Comment: @Holger Thank you. So now i can read up on the difference but where do  these optimizations come from? I ran the program without the JIT-Compiler `-XX:-UseCompiler` so i thought no optimizations would take place.

Comment: @Neintanke Which JVM did you use? Version, vendor?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov OpenJDK fastdebug build 11.0.4

Comment: Using an interpreter doesn’t imply the absence of optimizations. A lot of work is done only the first time, an instruction is executed. Most notably, linkage or resolving string or class constants. So in some cases, the instruction is replaced by a dedicated specialized instruction when all requirements are met. That’s an entirely different kind of optimizations than what JIT/Hotspot optimizers do.

Comment: @Holger Thanks alot. Searching for information about optimization results almost always in talk just about the JIT-Compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what exactly is the difference between these instructions?

In short: `fast_` variants are optimized architecture dependent instruction replacements

> Where do these optimizations come from?

The JVM module interpreter. It can work in non-patching and patching modes. Some related JVM options:

`RewriteBytecodes` - Allow rewriting of bytecodes

`RewriteFrequentPairs` - Rewrite frequently used bytecode pairs into a single bytecode

...

Implementation - https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/tip/src/hotspot/share/interpreter/bytecodeInterpreter.cpp

And

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/tip/src/hotspot/share/interpreter/bytecodes.cpp - contains the definitions of a number of the fast bytecodes (see
`Bytecodes::initialize()`) where a set of fast bytecodes is defined. Also, the fast bytecodes can be defined in a platform dependent area of code. The rewritten bytecodes are architecture dependant. Well, at least,
some of them are, and some of them are not.

> When/why does the interpreter choose to use these?

JVM has the capability to rewrite the bytecode stream, for example
to combine common instruction pairs. At least most, if not all, of the bytecode transformations to the `fast_` versions are done simply for performance and can be disabled. Doing so impacts interpreter performance.